# trigger @ Execution plan.. Cartesian product

Tags: oracle11g, sql-execution-plan, cartesian-product

The idea is when a user runs a query and has a bad Cartesian who cost is above a certain threshold . Then oracle emails it to me and user. i have tried few things but they don't work on run time. If toad and sql developer can see the execution plan. then I believe there is information there I just find it. Or i may have to adopt another logic.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is probably not possible.

In theory, if you were really determined, you could generate fine-grained auditing (FGA) triggers for every table in your system that fire for every `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`, get the `SQL_ID` from `V$SESSION`, join to `V$SQL_PLAN`, and implements whatever logic you want.  That's technically possible but it would involve quite a bit of code and you'd be adding a potentially decent amount of overhead to every query in your system.  This is probably not practical.

Rather than trying to use a trigger, you could write a procedure that was scheduled to run every few minutes via the [DBMS_JOB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm) or [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) packages that would query `V$SESSION` for all active sessions, joined to `V$SQL_PLAN`, and implemented whatever logic you wanted.  That eliminates the overhead of trying to run a trigger every time any user executes any statement.  But it still involves a decent amount of code.

Rather than writing any code, depending on the business problem you're trying to solve, it may be easier to create [resource limits on the user's profile](http://psoug.org/reference/profiles.html) to let Oracle enforce limits on the amount of resources any single SQL statement can consume.  For example, you could set the user's `CPU_PER_CALL`, `LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL`, or `COMPOSITE_LIMIT` to limit the amount of CPU, the amount of logical I/O, or the composite limit of CPU and logical I/O that a single statement can do before Oracle kills it.

If you want even more control, you could use [Oracle Resource Manager](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ResourceManagerEnhancements9i.php).  That could allow you to do anything from prevent Oracle from running queries from certain users if they were estimated to run too long or to throttle the resources that a group of users can consume if there is contention over those resources.  Oracle can automatically move long-running queries from specific users to lower-priority groups, it can kill long-running queries automatically, it can prevent them from running in the first place, or any combination of those things.

Comment: thanks this has opened my mind to think differently. May i ask how is possible that applications like Toad and sql developer can and user like me Cant. or is this something you already have mentioned that i need a very big piece of code for that.

Comment: @Imran - There is nothing that prevents you from accessing the query plan (though it's far easier from a separate session which is what Toad and SQL Developer do).  You can join `V$SESSION` to `V$SQL_PLAN` on `SQL_ID` and see the query plan for the currently executing SQL statement in every session-- this is what you'd do if you wrote a scheduled job.  It's just that you'd need to write the logic to analyze the query plan and that most of the problems that people want to solve in this general space are better solved using profiles and/or Resource Manager.

Comment: Thank you Really Appreciate for the answer